# Java Security Manager for JRuby

Tags: security, jruby, java-security-manager

I'm allowing user supplied ruby code to run in server(java scripting), and since jruby doesn't support safe-levels as in ruby I'm thinking about using java's security manager.

Is this a good decision? Has anyone else implemented this? Are there any good articles/books/resources that introduce me to security manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a perfectly reasonable decision.

The article [Java Scripting and JRuby Examples](http://www.ics.muni.cz/~makub/ruby/) demonstrates using JRuby with the SecurityManager, so at least one other person was able to successfully implement this configuration.